# WordPress Membership 2 show custom user meta on email

Tags: wordpress

I've added a custom field to Membership 2's registration so that I can capture a telephone number. This is stored in `user_meta`.

How do I then create a custom variable for the email templates so I can put this inside of the Welcome email?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Get the user meta value by this code

```
$memvalue  = get_user_meta($user_id, 'Membership', true);
```

and the mail code

```
$to = 'myemailaddress';
$subject = 'Registration Confirmation'; 
$message  = "Hello User";
$message .= "Your Booking is confirmed \r\n\r\n";
$message .= "Your Number".$memvalue.",\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "Thanks!"."\r\n";
$headers = "From: Company Name <info@example.com>"."\r\n";                      
$mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

try this, It will work

Comment: Membership 2 has its own Welcome Email with its own designer. This is what I'm talking about modifying to inject my own variable into.